# Entity Framework/SQL Server. Выбрать коллекцию данных на основе массива из Id, где каждая запись будет уникальна и соответствовать условию

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть таблица **ItemHistory**

```
 -----------------------------------
| Id | ItemId | DateTimeUtc         |
|-----------------------------------|
| 1  | 1      | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
|----|------------------------------|
| 2  | 2      | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
|----|------------------------------|
| 3  | 2      | 2021-01-01 12:50:00 |
|----|------------------------------|
| 4  | 1      | 2021-01-02 17:00:00 |
|----|------------------------------|
| 5  | 3      | 2021-02-24 16:59:00 |
|----|------------------------------|
|... |...     | ...                 |
------------------------------------
```

**Необходимо** реализовать выборку данных, которая будет принимать коллекцию `ItemId` и время `dateTimeUtc`, и будет возвращать для каждого `Item` наиболее близкую запись по времени (т.е. чтобы разница `Abs(DateTimeUtc - dateTimeUtc)` была минимальной). Как я понимаю, нужно сгрупировать данные по `ItemId` и отсортировать в каждой группе по `Math.Abs((x.DateTimeUtc - dateTimeUtc).TotalMilliseconds` и выбрать первую запись из каждой группы. Мои жалкие попытки что-либо сделать:

```
var result = context.Set<ItemHistory>()
    .Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x.VehicleId))
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
    .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((x.DateTimeUtc - dateTimeUtc).TotalMilliseconds))
    .ToList();
```

Но это, понятное дело, не компилируется (на строке `OrderBy` ошибка). В группировках не силен, как и в принципе в EntityFramework. Поэтому прошу помощи.

Принимаю ответы как на c#, так и на sql

P.S. Заголовок вопроса было сложно сформулировать.

---

Версия EntityFramework:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: Возможно, помогут [DbFunctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) - использовать для вычитания дат

Comment: Я в EF не шарю, но если бы надо было сделать с помощью обычного `Linq`, то получилось бы что-то такое `.GroupBy(x => x.ItemId).Select(g => new { ItemId = g.Key, DateTimeUtc = g.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((x.DateTimeUtc - dateTimeUtc).TotalSeconds)).First().DateTimeUtc }).ToList()`.

Comment: Или даже так `.GroupBy(x => x.ItemId).Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((x.DateTimeUtc - dateTimeUtc).TotalSeconds)).First()).ToList()`

Comment: @aepot спасибо, что-то совсем запутался в этих группировках. Завтра попробую ваш вариант + применю DbFunctions, которые предложил Alexander Petrov. Код написал уже, но запущу на реальных данных завтра

Comment: @aepot совсем забыл про этот вопрос. Ваш способ подошел мне. Единственное, из-за отсутствия в таблице индекса данные с таким запросом выгружаются очень долго, поэтому пришлось сначала достать все данные за 1 день и уже к ним применить фильтр. Не желаете оформить ответ?

Comment: Укажите точную версию EF

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  добавил в вопрос

Comment: Я бы всё-таки хотел добить решение вопроса. Код в ответе аепота в принципе не будет работать в EF. Если он у вас работает, и учитывая, что вы сетуете на плохую производительность, значит у вас где-то происходит трансформация в `IEnumerable`, в результате чего вся таблица из БД вытягивается на клиента.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вообще, да, согласен с вами. Это моя оплошность, я не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос. Меня здесь больше интересовал LINQ, а я почему-то сделал акцент на EF. Выше в своем комментарии я написал, что дело в отсутствии индекса, в связи с чем я просто решил выгрузить данные из базы без сортировки с условием `WHERE`, а затем уже на сервере с помощью LINQ нашел ближайшее (с помощью кода aepot). Ничего лучше не придумалось в тот момент. Создавать индекс для меня не вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я EF не знаю, но если бы надо было сделать с помощью обычного Linq, то получилось бы что-то такое

```cs
.GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
.Select(g => new
{
    ItemId = g.Key,
    DateTimeUtc = g.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((x.DateTimeUtc - dateTimeUtc).TotalSeconds))
        .First().DateTimeUtc
}).ToList();
```

Или даже так

```cs
.GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
.Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((x.DateTimeUtc - dateTimeUtc).TotalSeconds)).First())
.ToList();
```

Comment: Коллега, с золотым знаком по метке!

Comment: @AK спасибо! Уже опробовал. :)

Comment: Я видел: закрыли вопрос как дубль и топикстартер его удалил. )

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework не может обработать все выражения, допустимые в коде C#. В частности, разность типов DateTime нужно реализовывать с помощью методов класса [DbFunctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).
Дополнительно необходимо приведение к `int`, иначе там маячит `int?`, который не принимает `Math.Abs`.
И метод `First` необходимо заменить на `FirstOrDefault`. EF слишком привередлив.

```
var result = context.Set<ItemHistory>()
    .Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x.ItemId))
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((int)DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(x.DateTimeUtc, dateTimeUtc))).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

В комментариях вы пишете, что данные выгружаются долго.
Предлагаю попробовать следующие запросы.

```
var result = context.Set<ItemHistory>()
    .Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x.ItemId))
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(x =>
        Math.Abs((int)DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(x.DateTimeUtc, dateTimeUtc)) ==
        g.Min(y => Math.Abs((int)DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(y.DateTimeUtc, dateTimeUtc)))))
    .ToList();
```

или

```
var result = (from x in context.Set<ItemHistory>()
              where itemIds.Contains(x.ItemId)
              group x by x.ItemId into g
              let min = g.Min(x => Math.Abs((int)DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(x.DateTimeUtc, dateTimeUtc)))
              select g.FirstOrDefault(x => Math.Abs((int)DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(x.DateTimeUtc, dateTimeUtc)) == min))
             .ToList();
```

Выглядят они более страшно, но, возможно, окажутся быстрей, так как в них нет сортировки.

---

Советую включить логирование запросов:

```
context.Database.Initialize(false);
context.Database.Log += Console.Write;
```

Первая строка выполнит инициализацию контекста перед включением логирования и в лог не попадёт неважный для нас sql-код.

Все три запроса выглядят громоздкими и неэффективными. Я ожидал, что сгенерированный sql для второго и третьего окажется одинаковым, но оказалось, что это не так.

Попробуйте их на больших объёмах данных и отпишитесь о результатах.

Comment: К сожалению, пока нет возможности проверить скорость выполнения вашего запроса. С `DbFunctions` я пробовал, ощутимо скорости не прибавляло. Там основная проблема в том, что данных в таблице очень много, а нужного индекса предыдущие разработчики не добавили. Может быть, проверю ваш способ, но вряд ли это будет скоро

Comment: @AndreiKhotko - так ведь без DbFunctions оно вообще работать не будет. Эти функции не для скорости нужны.